# Append columns to data.table, sort and avoid setDT

Tags: r, data.table

I have some simple data table code - it works (almost) perfectly but I'm sure it can be improved.

I have searched online but couldn't find a solution for this scenario.

Here is my code:

```
library(data.table)
df <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x <- df[Question.Number==9, .(sum(LoadedCount)), keyby = .(Provider)]
y <- df[Question.Number==9 & Response!='no experience', .(sum(Count)), keyby = .(Provider)]
z <- list(x$Provider, x$V1/y$V1)
setDT(z)
a <- z[, .(Provider = V1, TotalAverage = V2), keyby=.(TotalAverage = V2)]
a
```

The result is

```
 TotalAverage        Provider TotalAverage
 1:    0.7312500         A    0.7312500
 2:    0.7334416         B    0.7334416
 3:    0.7451613         C    0.7451613
 4:    0.7823718         D    0.7823718
 5:    0.7904412         E    0.7904412
 6:    0.8151316         F    0.8151316
 7:    0.8172840         G    0.8172840
 8:    0.8327586         H    0.8327586
 9:    0.8363333         I    0.8363333
10:    0.8893939         J    0.8893939
```

Questions: 
Can I do x/y on one row or more efficiently? 
If I do need the step z, how to make it a table directly (without List and setDT)?
How can I sort step 'a' by TotalAverage without that column being repeated?

Thank you so much!

Comment: May I suggest you to be more specific in your question title?

Comment: You should provide sample data. Also, instead of ```read.csv```, use ```fread```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like (caveat not tested with any data):

```
setDT(df)[Question.Number==9, {
        x <- sum(LoadedCount)
        .(TotalAverage = x / .SD[Response!='no experience', sum(Count)])
    }, 
    keyby=.(Provider)]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the advice of @chinsoon12 & @cole I came up with the solution:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("data.csv")
x <- DT[`Question Number` == 9, {
      g <- sum(LoadedCount)
      .(TotalAverage = g / .SD[Response != 'no experience', sum(Count)])
  },
  keyby=.(Provider)][order(TotalAverage)]
```